# Displaying records only when there are more than same three values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to display only records where one email corresponds to more than 3 names?

I have tried the code below, but it does not return anything.

```
SELECT 
t1.Name, t2.Email 
FROM 
Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.ID=t2.PersonID
GROUP BY 
t1.Name, t2.Email
HAVING COUNT(t2.Email) > 3
```

Comment: You need to understand how group by and having clauses work. The first step is to remove the having clause and add count to the select list. Execute the code and then find an email value that is used at least 3 times for different names. Now - what value is displayed for count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your version supports window function then you can do :

```
select t.*
from (select t1.name, t2.email,
             count(t2.email) over (partition by t1.name) as cnt
      from t1 inner join
           t2
           on t2.personid = t1.id
     ) t
where cnt > 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT t1.Name, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.Email)
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN
     Table2 t2 
     ON t1.ID = t2.PersonID
GROUP BY t1.Name
HAVING COUNT(t2.Email) > 3;
```

The big change is to the `GROUP BY` -- this does not have `EMAIL`.  You seem to want the emails returns on each row, so this concatenates them together.

EDIT:

In SQL Server, you would use `string_agg()`:

```
SELECT t1.Name, STRING_AGG(t2.Email, ',')
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN
     Table2 t2 
     ON t1.ID = t2.PersonID
GROUP BY t1.Name
HAVING COUNT(t2.Email) > 3;
```

Or, if you want individual rows:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM (SELECT t1.Name, t2.Email,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Name) as cnt
      FROM Table1 t1 JOIN
           Table2 t2 
           ON t1.ID = t2.PersonID
     ) n
WHERE cnt > 3
ORDER BY Name;
```

Comment: By mistake I added mysql instead of sql-server as a tag. `GROUP_CONCAT` is not a sql-server function. Is there any similar function in sql-server?